# Is there a way to adjust image size in a button in iOS?

Tags: ios, storyboard, swift5

As seen in the image below, the image of the button is crossing the button boundaries. Is there a way to make the image fit in the boundaries of the button either through the storyboard or programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Button `Style` from `Plain` to `Default`:

[image]

Here is a button constrained to `60 x 60` with a `80 x 80` image with `Style: Plain`:

[image]

and with `Style: Default`:

[image]