# Scale image on button in cell

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am adding buttons programmatically to a collectionview. The images are all the same size (512px x 512px). I want the cell to be centered and it's size to be 250x250.
I changed the size of the `Collection View Cell` to  `Custom` and set the Width and Height in the inspector. In `Collection Reusable View` I have changed the Content Mode to `Scale To Fill`. My button has in the `View`section the Content Mode also set to `Scale To Fill`. My Images are not scaled and look like in the screenshot. Thanks for help.

Here's the code where I add the Buttons with images:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell
        let appButton = cell.MyButton!
        cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell.clipsToBounds = true
        //appButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        appButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        appButton.setImage(UIImage(named: webSeriesImage[indexPath.row]), for: .normal)
        appButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        appButton.clipsToBounds = true
        appButton.tag = indexPath.row
        //appButton.imageView?.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.3, 0.3, 0.3)
        appButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.contentMode = .redraw
        appButton.contentMode = .redraw
        return cell
    }
```

[image: Screenshot with not scaled image]

Edit:

I really tried a lot of things. Last thing I tried was:

```
cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
cell.clipsToBounds = true
```

None of these worked for me.

Comment: Is this what you're running into? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72546589/6257435

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for this - I have to wait until monday with this because my mac is at work. :)

Comment: @DonMag That was the mistake. Thank you very much.